# NetCDF: HDF error is shown while running calculations of multiple netcdf files

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

I am trying to do calculations around ~2900 of netcdf files (of particular year) using xarray. I could open and do calculations over a month and save output into a netcdf file, but when I try to do it with all the 2900 files of a year it shows errors.

```
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.10.2) thread 140228459226880:
  #000: H5Dio.c line 216 in H5Dread(): can't read data
    major: Dataset
    minor: Read failed
  #001: H5Dio.c line 587 in H5D__read(): can't read data
    major: Dataset
    minor: Read failed
  #002: H5Dchunk.c line 2304 in H5D__chunk_read(): unable to read raw data chunk
    major: Low-level I/O
    minor: Read failed
  #003: H5Dchunk.c line 3659 in H5D__chunk_lock(): data pipeline read failed
    major: Data filters
    minor: Filter operation failed
  #004: H5Z.c line 1279 in H5Z_pipeline(): filter returned failure during read
    major: Data filters
    minor: Read failed
  #005: H5Zdeflate.c line 123 in H5Z_filter_deflate(): inflate() failed
    major: Data filters
    minor: Unable to initialize object
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.10.2) thread 140228459226880:
  #000: H5Dio.c line 216 in H5Dread(): can't read data
    major: Dataset
    minor: Read failed
  #001: H5Dio.c line 587 in H5D__read(): can't read data
    major: Dataset
    minor: Read failed
  #002: H5Dchunk.c line 2304 in H5D__chunk_read(): unable to read raw data chunk
    major: Low-level I/O
    minor: Read failed
  #003: H5Dchunk.c line 3659 in H5D__chunk_lock(): data pipeline read failed
    major: Data filters
    minor: Filter operation failed
  #004: H5Z.c line 1279 in H5Z_pipeline(): filter returned failure during read
    major: Data filters
    minor: Read failed
  #005: H5Zdeflate.c line 123 in H5Z_filter_deflate(): inflate() failed
    major: Data filters
    minor: Unable to initialize object
```

and showing a traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-55-24c15821ac5d>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/home/atmosphere/data/xarray_datetime_imp.py', wdir='/home/atmosphere/data')

  File "/home/atmosphere/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 786, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/home/atmosphere/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/home/atmosphere/data/xarray_datetime_imp.py", line 23, in <module>
    pi=dm.where(dm.values<230)

  File "/home/atmosphere/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/dataarray.py", line 568, in values
    return self.variable.values

  File "/home/atmosphere/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/variable.py", line 437, in values
    return _as_array_or_item(self._data)

  File "/home/atmosphere/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/variable.py", line 250, in _as_array_or_item
    data = np.asarray(data)

  File "/home/atmosphere/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 538, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)

  File "/home/atmosphere/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/array/core.py", line 998, in __array__
    x = self.compute()

  File "/home/atmosphere/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 156, in compute
    (result,) = compute(self, traverse=False, **kwargs)

  File "/home/atmosphere/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 398, in compute
    results = schedule(dsk, keys, **kwargs)

  File "/home/atmosphere/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/threaded.py", line 76, in get
    pack_exception=pack_exception, **kwargs)

  File "/home/atmosphere/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 462, in get_async
    raise_exception(exc, tb)

  File "/home/atmosphere/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/compatibility.py", line 112, in reraise
    raise exc

  File "/home/atmosphere/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 230, in execute_task
    result = _execute_task(task, data)

  File "/home/atmosphere/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/core.py", line 119, in _execute_task
    return func(*args2)

  File "/home/atmosphere/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/array/core.py", line 82, in getter
    c = np.asarray(c)

  File "/home/atmosphere/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 538, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)

  File "/home/atmosphere/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/indexing.py", line 490, in __array__
    return np.asarray(self.array, dtype=dtype)

  File "/home/atmosphere/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 538, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)

  File "/home/atmosphere/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/indexing.py", line 652, in __array__
    return np.asarray(self.array, dtype=dtype)

  File "/home/atmosphere/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 538, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)

  File "/home/atmosphere/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/indexing.py", line 556, in __array__
    return np.asarray(array[self.key], dtype=None)

  File "/home/atmosphere/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 538, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)

  File "/home/atmosphere/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/coding/variables.py", line 73, in __array__
    return self.func(self.array)

  File "/home/atmosphere/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/coding/variables.py", line 214, in _scale_offset_decoding
    data = np.array(data, dtype=dtype, copy=True)

  File "/home/atmosphere/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/coding/variables.py", line 73, in __array__
    return self.func(self.array)

  File "/home/atmosphere/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/coding/variables.py", line 142, in _apply_mask
    data = np.asarray(data, dtype=dtype)

  File "/home/atmosphere/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 538, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)

  File "/home/atmosphere/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/indexing.py", line 556, in __array__
    return np.asarray(array[self.key], dtype=None)

  File "/home/atmosphere/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/backends/netCDF4_.py", line 72, in __getitem__
    key, self.shape, indexing.IndexingSupport.OUTER, self._getitem

  File "/home/atmosphere/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/indexing.py", line 836, in explicit_indexing_adapter
    result = raw_indexing_method(raw_key.tuple)

  File "/home/atmosphere/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/backends/netCDF4_.py", line 84, in _getitem
    array = getitem(original_array, key)

  File "netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx", line 4119, in netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable.__getitem__

  File "netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx", line 5036, in netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable._get

  File "netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx", line 1754, in netCDF4._netCDF4._ensure_nc_success

RuntimeError: NetCDF: HDF error
```

Why does it shows this error? How can I rectify this?